# Can I use `try?` with a generic method?

Tags: swift, generics, try-catch

I have a generic throwing method:

```
func doSomething<T>() throws -> T? {
    // do something
}
```

This is how I want to call it:

```
let obj: SomeClass? = try? doSomething()    // a compiler error!
```

But I may not. The compiler gives me an error

> Value of optional type `'SomeClass??'` not unwrapped; did you mean to use `'try!'` or chain with `'?'`?.

I can use `try!` or `try` instead. But I don't like the former because it might crash the app at some point, and I don't like the latter because it's too long for most of the cases (one line becomes five).

Does anybody know how can I keep using `try?`?

Comment: I think you are missing the point about `??`. Your code is not correct.

Comment: 1) I expect it to return an object of a class which implements some protocol; 2) this method is defined in a class extension

Comment: It's curious that you both want the function to return an optional and throw. Surely it would make more sense to only throw in the case of the function failing, rather than a combination of throwing and potentially returning `nil`? `try?` would then consolidate both cases into a single-level optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is returning an optional. The `try?` expression adds another level of optional, therefore your expected return value should be a double optional:

```
let obj: SomeClass?? = try? doSomething()
```

It's probably not a good idea to combine returning of optional and `throws`.

You could also remove the second level of optionals using `??`:

```
let obj: SomeClass? = (try? doSomething()) ?? nil
```

but I really recommend to redesign the API instead of solving double optionals.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. Frankly, I didn't even know that an optional an optional type exists. What sense does it make? Why the compiler simply doesn't suppress it to a normal optional?

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko I assure you that nested optionals make perfect sense and they are needed and the compiler doesn't want to suppress them.

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko It makes absolutely perfect sense to have two layers of "optionality". In this case, the first layer corresponds to whether or not the method threw. It's either `Optional.none` (a.k.a. `nil`) if the method threw an error, or it's `Optional<T?>.some(optionalResult)`, where `optionalResult ` is the `T?` returned successfully by `doSomething` without throwing. Then the second layer of optionality is that of `T?`, which could either be `Optional.none` (a.k.a `nil`) or `Optional<T>.some(result)`, where result is the `T` result returned by `doSomething`.

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko And to answer `Why the compiler simply doesn't suppress it to a normal optional?`. The compiler *could* do that, but it shouldn't. Suppose the result was just a `T?`, instead of the `T??` it currently is. How can I distinguish between the case that `doSomething` threw an error, vs `doSomething` completing successfully but returning `nil`. Under your proposal, both cases would result in just a `nil`, which doesn't allow you to disambiguate between the two possibilities

Comment: @Alexander but why do you want to distinguish these two cases based on the returned value? If you catch an exception, you know there's the exception, if you don't – there's none. Isn't it enough?

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko There's no catching going on here. The whole point of `try?` is to eliminate the need of using `do { try doSomething() } catch {}` in the case where you don't care to check what kind of error happened.

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko Say I ask a web server who the currently logged in user is. That function might `throw` (such as if there's an error in the network. It returns `User?` (because no user might be logged in). If there's an error thrown, I want to retry. If there's no user logged in, I don't need to retry, but I need to know to take special action (perhaps present a log-in interface)

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko If the compiler collapsed nested optionals into a single optional, then I lose the ability to distinguish between those very different results.

Comment: If you understand pointers, it's very similar to the difference between `**var` and `*var`. Both can be `NULL` but they mean very different things.

Comment: Guys, thank you so much for the clarification. Your examples make a perfect sense. My problem is that I thought of a return value and an exception as completely different entities. I didn't realize that the exception has a reflection in the return value. My bad.

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko The change in return type (the wrapping of the original return into another layer of optionality) is a result of `try?`. If you were using `try` or `try!`, this wouldn't be the case.